# How do I consolidate a node|types by rel|types to a single Node|Type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Context:
I'm working on an Alumni project to understand the difference between giving and engagement. (engagement = showing up, attending events, volunteering, etc.) The value in the work will come from the insight gained from understanding the behavior partners.

In the query below I've been effective at bring back the "Biggest spenders", however I'd like to list the name of the (n) Alumni and the (a,b)gifts. There 30 gift types that fit into (a,b).

Please let me know your thoughts... Innosoljim

```
>//Who are Alumni that give the most?
>>MATCH (n:Alumni)-[r:Supportfin]->(b)
>>MATCH (n:Alumni)-[t:Gavefin]->(a)
>>RETURN n,b,a LIMIT 1500
```

Thanks for the Answer - Let me restate the goal for clarity: I'm trying to consolidate (into n.Alumni) many relationships -[Gave|Support]-> to unique nodes (Various Gifts) so that I can obtain a report on an Alumni's activity (giving, support, by n.name. The Graph model places the Alumni node at the center of each unique behavior (giving, support, graddate, address, degree, greeklife, etc....) Does this help?

```
MATCH (a:Alumni)-[r:Supportfin|Gavefin]->(gift)
RETURN a.name, collect(gift)
ORDER BY (a)-[r:Supportfin|Gavefin]-> count(*) DESC
```

Something like this maybe although this isn't working (syntaxerror)

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you want. Maybe you could provide an example of desired output for a given subgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match Alumni to the gifts with both relationship types and return:

```
MATCH (a:Alumni)-[r:r:Supportfin|Gavefin]->(gift)
RETURN a.name, collect(gift)
```

Or split it by the different relationship types:

```
MATCH (a:Alumni)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:Supportfin]->(sup_gift)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:Gavefin]->(gave_gift)
RETURN a.name, collect(DISTINCT sup_gift), collect(DISTINCT gave_gift)
```

Without a proper decription of your graph model and problem the question is difficult to answer.